# Removing line break and tabulators under specific condition

Tags: python, regex

Please help me with 2 topics:

1) I've got a long file which is structured like below - line should start with 500. However there are lines not starting with 500 (Line 2, Line 4) which should be merged with the line above (so Line 2 with Line 1, etc.). How I can easily do it in python (2.7)?

2) Also you can see that I have many tabulators in between - how I can remove not needed ones and then replace tabs to pipes or semicolons so the file could be loaded to the db? Normally one tab correspond with one column.

INPUT

```
Line 1: 500  94449  YUUUII  VP      0017A4775           
YPAYREQ
Line 2: BOS                 MA                                                                                                                                                          
5           0.00             1,000.00              0.00            0.00               
0.00                 0.00                    0.00                  0.00                
0.00
Line 3: 500  98220  YPO_INV KP      0017A4775           
YNOUINU
Line 4: MARTHJJIU                                                                                                                                                                               
5       8,000.00             8,000.00              0.00            0.00               
0.00                 0.00                    0.00                  0.00                                                 
C4
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Line 1: 500;94449;YUUUII;VP;0017A4775;YPAYREQ;BOS;  
MA;5;0.00;1,000.00;0.00;.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
Line 2: 500;98220;YPO_INV;KP;0017A47758;YNOUINU;
MARTHJJIU;;5;8,000.00;8,000.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;C4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `\s+(?!\s|^500)` with `;` in [multiline mode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

`\s+(?!\s|^500)` matches one or more space characters that are not followed by another space or by a substring `500` at the begin of line.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/OJsAob/2

Comment: Apologies for a stupid question, but how I can modify the code to add the multiline mode?    
                
for l in lines:
                f.write(re.sub(r'\s+(?!\s|^500)', ';', l))# + '\n')

Comment: @user2433705 For multiline mode, you can use `(?m)\s+(?!\s|^500)`, see [example](https://regex101.com/r/OJsAob/3).

Comment: @user2433705 you may want to accept and/or upvote the answer, if it satisfied your doubts.